# How many pixels is a space equal to?

Tags: javascript, css, width, space

This is my code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
        <div contenteditable=true>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            aaaaa
            bbbbbbbbbbb
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to fill all of the space in the div.

How many pixels is the `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Depends on the browser, the font being rendered, etc.  There's no guaranteed value.  Sure there is a better way to accomplish what you're trying to do.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The question I have is... why are you trying to fill all of the horizontal space... what is the end goal? If you just wanted the text to be flush to the right, you can just use text-align: right on the div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `<div>` containing `&nbsp;` and assign an `id`. Set the font size and attributes. Then read the current width and height using:

```
var space=document.getElementById("space");
var height=(space.clientHeight+1)+"px";
var width=(space.clientWidth+1)+"px";
```

Comment: why +1 ?   var height=(space.clientHeight)+"px";  ,why cant use this  ?

Comment: Why the +1? (Also doesn't clientWidth include padding and border? If you'd need to make sure these are set to 0)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the font, size, etc. There's no direct equation/number for spaces to pixels.

Answer (score 2):

It's dependent on the font size because `&nbsp;` is a white-space character.

Answer (score 2):

An "em" (1 character width) is often considered to be 16 x 16 pixels.  Of course, if a viewer resizes text, that would change.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you just want empty space above your text, you could put another div (for the text) inside your div, and then set a " margin-top: 10em; " (or however many ems you want) to provide the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to answer this question honesty, as the size of one space changes depending on the font size.

Try this, changing the "30px" to whatever you want.

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:50px;height:50px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
        <div contenteditable=true style="margin-left: 30px;">
            aaaaa
            bbbbbbbbbbb
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the font you are using and the styles it has been given. So you'll need to calculate it dynamically in the page.

Use Javascript to create an div that is displayed off the page (i.e left:-4000px;} that contains one   character. Make sure this element has the same text styling as the your contentEditable div. The width of this element should be the width of the space character (make sure you're not including any padding or borders etc.)

I've not tried this, but that's what I'd try first.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "em" instead of "px". First googled link about "em": http://www.xs4all.nl/~sbpoley/webmatters/emex.html

Try such construction

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:{count_of_letters}em; height:50px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
    <div contenteditable=true>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        aaaaa
        bbbbbbbbbbb
    </div>
```

But better to forget this idea and use CSS rules from other comments in this topic.

Comment: *em* is the height of a line of text; it's usually a lot larger than the width of a space.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode defines fixed widths for a number of space characters. The following table from [here](https://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html) is a summary of Unicode's specs ([Unicode 14, p. 266](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode14.0.0/UnicodeStandard-14.0.pdf)):

> | Code | Name of the character | Width of the character |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | U+0020 | SPACE | Depends on font, typically 1/4 em, often adjusted |
> | U+00A0 | NO-BREAK SPACE | As a space, but often not adjusted |
> | U+1680 | OGHAM SPACE MARK | Unspecified; usually not really a space but a dash |
> | U+180E | MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR | 0 |
> | U+2000 | EN QUAD | 1 en (= 1/2 em) |
> | U+2001 | EM QUAD | 1 em (nominally, the height of the font) |
> | U+2002 | EN SPACE (nut) | 1 en (= 1/2 em) |
> | U+2003 | EM SPACE (mutton) | 1 em |
> | U+2004 | THREE-PER-EM SPACE (thick space) | 1/3 em |
> | U+2005 | FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (mid space) | 1/4 em |
> | U+2006 | SIX-PER-EM SPACE | 1/6 em |
> | U+2007 | FIGURE SPACE | “Tabular width”, the width of digits |
> | U+2008 | PUNCTUATION SPACE | The width of a period “.” |
> | U+2009 | THIN SPACE | 1/5 em (or sometimes 1/6 em) |
> | U+200A | HAIR SPACE | Narrower than THIN SPACE |
> | U+200B | ZERO WIDTH SPACE | 0 |
> | U+202F | NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE | Narrower than NO-BREAK SPACE (or SPACE), “typically the width of a thin space or a mid space” |
> | U+205F | MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE | 4/18 em |
> | U+3000 | IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE | The width of ideographic (CJK) characters. |
> | U+FEFF | ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE | 0 |

Unfortunately the common space is not defined as having a fixed width. It depends not only on font size and explicit styling, but also on zoom level and system display scaling, among other things.

However, `0.25em` will generally get you *close*. In pixels it would be 1/4 the font height; but you'd be better off using `calc()` if you are trying to fit *em* units to *px* dimensions, or just use *em*.

Alternatively, consider styling strategies that don't require you to know how  wide a space is. For the OP's goal of "fill all of the space in the div", for example, the `width` and `height` of the parent `div` could be set to `max-content`, or the child div could be styled as `white-space:nowrap`.

Or, for example, gaps in flex layouts could be replaced with pseudo elements, e.g. here an element containing a space with `white-space: pre` can be inserted to create a correctly sized gap:

```css
.explicit-gap { 
  gap: 0.25em; 
}

.implicit-space > :not(:first-child):before {
  content: ' ';
  white-space: pre;
}

div { display: flex; }

/* just some labels, nothing interesting down here */
.explicit-gap:after { content: "(using 'gap')" }
.implicit-space:after { content: "(using ':before')" }
.no-styling:after { content: "(no gap set)" }
.control:after { content: "(actual spaces)" }
div:after { position: absolute; left: 25ex; opacity:.5; }
```

```html
<div class="explicit-gap">
  <span>Here</span>
  <span>are</span>
  <span>some</span>
  <span>words</span>
</div>

<div class="implicit-space">
  <span>Here</span>
  <span>are</span>
  <span>some</span>
  <span>words</span>
</div>

<div class="no-styling">
  <span>Here</span>
  <span>are</span>
  <span>some</span>
  <span>words</span>
</div>

<div class="control">
  <span>Here are some words</span>
</div>
```

Etc.